# Mardown files always have vimwiki filetype (vimwiki plugin)

Tags: filetype, filetype-markdown, plugin-vimwiki

Here is the relevant content of my `.vimrc`

```
let g:vimwiki_global_ext=0
let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path': 'C:\Users\<USER>\vimwiki',
                     \ 'syntax': 'markdown', 'ext': '.md'}]
```

The plugin mapping `<leader>ww` creates a new file called `index.md` in `C:\Users\<USER>\vimwiki` as expected. So I suppose `path` is correct.

My problem is that `:set ft?` of the `index.md` file is always set to `vimwiki` (`filetype=vimwiki`). I don't know what settings are wrong here?

Note that vimwiki is in `/opt` instead of `/start`.

Answer (score 10):

This is the expected behavior of the plugin when you create a file in your vimwiki the filetype is set to `vimwiki`.

If you don't want files created outside of the wiki directory to have this filetype you can follow [this issue](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/95) and add the following line to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:vimwiki_global_ext = 0
```

Comment: How to set `.md` file in wiki directory has filetype `mardown`?. Because of highlights depend on filetype, if a buffer use markdown syntax but has filetype `vimwiki`, the highlight is totally incorrect.

Comment: @TuyenPham To force the markdown filetype you could use an autocommand like `autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost /path/to/vimwiki/* set filetype=markdown` but I think that might break the plugin. You should try asking your question to the maintainer directly on the plugin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues)

Comment: Didn't work: `autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost C:\Users\<USER>\vimwiki\* set filetype=markdown` in `vimrc`, restart gvim and it's still `vimwiki` from `:set ft?`. I already asked in issue tracker but haven't got reply yet.

Comment: Thanks, I have added this option in my vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kind of old but if someone still comes here for a solution.
My problem was that i wanted to have filetype to markdown so that my lsp formatting could work.
Using autocmd will break the plugin. Instead fixed it by setting this:

```
vim.g.vimwiki_filetypes = { "markdown" }
```